# How to stop VS Code importing react methods from Minified React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

At some point, my VS Code has started to import react hooks from `react/cjs/react.production.min`, not from `react`.
This annoys me because it only causes errors when I'm developing on my localhost:3000 even with simple hooks such as `useState`, `useEffect`, etc.. Is there a way to configure VS Code to import React materials from 'react'? I am tired of manually fixing import statements.
The first pic is the error page I get on Next JS, and the second pic is showing how VS Code automatically imports useState from Minified React. The line above it is the ones I manually fixed.
[image: nextjs error]

[image: imports]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can try to install the **Auto Import**

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport

or simple reinstall your vscode maybe the fastest way to resolve it

Comment: Thank you. Auto Import solved the issue!

Comment: Auto import didn't solve the issue for me!

Answer (score 1):

Following Rivers answer "Auto Import - ES6, TS, JSX, TSX" worked for me since I don't use Typescript.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuclleaR.vscode-extension-auto-import

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, out of nowhere, VS Code started to do the same on my computer -- not suggesting imports from `react` package. I tried to install **Auto Import** but it didn't fix the issue. Thinking about it, I recalled the problem started after the IDE suggested using the Workspace's TypeScript version instead of VS Code's. To fix the issue I did the following:

**Open the Command Palette**

With <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, depending on your OS, and enter "typescript".  This will bring up a few suggestions.

[image: VSCode's Command Palette showing suggestions matching "typescript"]

**Change the TypeScript Version**

Press the arrow down (<kbd>↓</kbd>) until you reach the **TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version...** option.

This will bring up another modal to select which version you want to use. In my case, I had the **Use Workspace Version** option selected. Changing it back to **Use VS Code's Version** did the trick.

[image: Picking a TypeScript version]

I'm not sure exactly why this was happening -- perhaps there are some settings attached to the editor version -- but trying to import things like `useState` or anything from `react` package started to work again.